# Default <current view> settings for Blog Categories web part?

Tags: list-view, blog, categories, rendering

What are the default settings for the out of the box  list settings for the *Categories* page of a Blog site?

I lost the settings for mine. How do I discover what the old settings were and re-apply them? None of the selections in the web part list box have the old settings.

[image: Screenshot: web-part view selection list]

I was editing the Categories page, and in the Web Part when I changed the "List Views" (above image) the rendering changed from the nicely formatted headings and metadata (*After* screenshot) to a table-like listing (*Before* screenshot. Since at this point I had changed nothing on this page I assumed that one of the item in the drop down list would be the same as `<Current View>`.

**After** - what a categories page looks like now:

[image: screenshot: mostly just a table list]

**Before** - what it used to look like (from a different blog on same SP farm, ignore different category names):

[image: Screenshot: title formatted as Heading, author & comments as byline]

I've also compared the settings for other blog pages on the same farm and don't see anything to copy over (`.../blog/_layouts/15/listedit.aspx?List={list-id-#}`}. None of these seem to apply:

[image: screnshot List setting page]

Comment: I am not sure if your problem is related to the catetories. What do you see wen you go to this page /sites/tgg/blog/Lists/Categories/AllCategories.aspx? You should be seeing Ideas, Opinions, Events. These are the default categories.

Comment: @Aslan - It's not the default category names I'm missing, but the default view. I was editing the Categories page, and in the Web Part when I changed the "List Views" the rendering changed from the nicely formatted headings and metadata (2nd blog screenshot) to a table-like listing (1st screen shot). Since I had changed nothing on this page yet I assumed that one of the items listed would be the same as <Current View>. [Q updated]

Comment: do you have /sites/tgg/blog/Lists/Posts/AllPosts.aspx ? and did you compare the selected columns in the AllPosts view? maybe you are missing some fields...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think this will solve your problem:

1. Edit **/sites/tgg/blog/default.aspx**
2. Edit **Posts** webpart
3. Set Selected view "**`<Summary view>`**"
4. Set Toolbar Type "**`<Summary Toolbar>`**"
5. Click **Apply** then **OK**
6. **Save** the page

The page will not look as expected until the step 6.

Comment: Hmmm.  Didn't do it. Summary View shows the whole post, same as the Blog front page. I'm starting to wonder if the `<Summary View>` list itself has been broken somehow.

Comment: Actually Categories is completely broken now, no matter which one I pick they all show same content as front page. :-/

Comment: Have you seen this post https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/90986/no-way-to-restore-a-post-aspx-blog-view

Comment: No I hadn't. That sounds very like what's happened here. Previously I haven't been able to get Sharepoint Designer to work with our sharepoint and mapped network drives to SP are disabled, so I can't use the solutions there. However it might be enough info to get someone in central IT to do something. Thanks.